# How to get result list from parsec?

Tags: haskell, parsec

As the code blow, I can use <* to bind two parser, but it only return the first result.

How can I bind the parser and get the result list?

the result I get now is

```
*Main> parserAll "111|"
Right (Str "111")
*Main> parserAll "111"
Left "123" (line 1, column 4):
unexpected end of input
expecting letter, digit, white space or "|"
```

And I want get result is

```
*Main> parserAll "111|"
Right [(Str "111"),(Str "｜")]
```

or

```
*Main> parserAll "111|"
Left "123" (line 1, column 4):
[Right (Str "111"),Right (Str "|")]
```

code========

```
data SimpleExpr = Num Integer
                 | Var String
                 | Add SimpleExpr SimpleExpr
                 | Parens SimpleExpr
                 | Str [Char]
                   deriving (Eq,Show)

arser4search:: Parser SimpleExpr
parser4search = do
    spaces
    searchStr <- many1 (choice [letter,digit])
    spaces
    return (Str searchStr)
    --if searchStr ==[]
    --  then return (Num 0)
    --  else return (Num (read searchStr))

parserSeparator:: Parser SimpleExpr
parserSeparator = do 
    spaces 
    tStr <- (char '|')
    spaces
    return (Str [tStr]) 

parseBuilder =  parser4search <* parserSeparator

parserAll s = parse  parseBuilder "123" s
```

Comment: Could you give an example of what result you expect, and what you are getting?

Comment: You're aware that `(<*)` basically ignores the results (not the effects) of the right parser?

Comment: @luqui I had edit the question to add example and what I expect.

Comment: @Zeta Yes, I had read the doc for "Control.Applicative". But I don't find any function can do "Sequence actions, not discarding the value of the second argument."

Comment: You want something like `(,) <$> parser4search <*> parserSeparator`, which will collect the results of the two parsers into a tuple.  You can also use `do` notation: `do { s <- parser4search; sep <- parserSeparator; return (s, sep) }`. The point is you need to say *how* to collect the results.

Comment: Do you want to combine exactly two results or many? You can do `combiningFunction <$> parser4search <*> parserSeparator` to combine exactly two using some function `combiningFunction :: SimpleExpression -> SimpleExpression -> resulttype`, or you could use the `many` combinator to make a list.